# Can't create folder in external storage on Nexus 5X Android 6.0

Tags: android, storage

I have set permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

I tried create directory with this code:

```
    // test external storage root
    String myDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File f = new File(myDir);
    if(f.exists()) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "folder exists: " + f.toString());
    }else {
        Log.d("MyApp", "folder does not exist: " + f.toString());
    }
    // try create folder
    myDir +=  File.separator + "MyFolder";
    f = new File(myDir);
    if(f.exists()) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "folder exists: " + f.toString());
    }else{
        Log.d("MyApp", "folder does not exist: " + f.toString());
        if(f.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyApp", "folder created: " + f.toString());
        }else{
            Log.d("MyApp", "cannot create: " + f.toString());
        }

    }
```

On tablets with Android 4 and 5 is this functionally, but on Nexus 5X with Android 6.0 looks like:

```
D/MyApp: folder exists: /storage/emulated/0
D/MyApp: folder does not exist: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder
D/MyApp: cannot create: /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder
```

Is in Nexus 5X or Android 6.0 some sweet secret I don't know?

Comment: Yes, the reason in [Can't Get the Permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission) is right, thank you! But the question couldn't be found until was clear the origin of problem - new permition rules.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to write directly to CommonsWare, so I write it here. I guess this is not duplicate question, this are 2 questions with 1 answer. If I would find solution for sending SMS, I would close it, because I don't want send message, I want to write to storage. Please remove forwarding to another question.